# (SCHEME) Number -> English List

Tags: scheme, racket, number-formatting, r5rs

Okay. So I'm wondering how to create a function that will turn a random number into its english word component.

Such as (1001 -> '(one thousand one) or 0 -> '(zero) 
and (number-name factorial 20 -> ’(two quintillion four hundred thirty two quadrillion nine hundred two
trillion eight billion one hundred seventy six million six hundred
forty thousand))

I worked with a previous user on stackoverflow to get something that turned a long number into 3 part digits (1,341,100 is one million, 341 thousand 1 hundred 0 tens 0 ones)

```
 #lang r5rs
 (define (three-names n)
   (if (zero? n)
  "zero"
  (let loop ((n n)
             (units '((10 one) (10 ten) (10 hundred) (1000 thousand) (1000 million)  (1000 billion) (1000 trillion) (1000 quadrillion) (1000 quintillion)
                             (1000 sextillion) (1000 septillion) (1000 octillion) (1000 nonillion)
                             (1000 decillion) (1000 undecillion) (1000 duodecillion) (1000 tredecillion)
                             (1000 quatturodecillion) (1000 sexdillion) (1000 septendecillion) (1000 octodecillion)
                             (1000 novemdecillion) (1000 vigintillion)))
             (ARRAY '()))

    (if
     (or (zero? n) (null? units)) 
        ARRAY
        (let* ((unit (car units)) (div (car unit)) (english (cadr unit)))
          (let
              ((q (quotient n div)) (r (remainder n div)))
            (loop q
                  (cdr units)
                  (cons r (cons english ARRAY)))))))))
```

The only thing I understand right now is to make it so that there are values for 0-20:

```
 (= x 0) zero
 (= x 1) one
 ...
 (> x 1000) thousand
 (> x 1000000) million
```

But for one, these won't be outputted into a list and two, not sure what else to do?

Comment: And how is this different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35530887/201359)?

Comment: The output is similar, yet very different. Instead of having 3 numbers followed by the placeholder (thousands, or tens) it is the entire string being returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sylwester explains you need to be able to

1. correctly print the text for every number below 1000 (3 digits)
2. divide the number in 3-digits groups, print them using above code and just append the "thousands" suffices

Here's an example implementation that is compatible with Racket's r5rs language:

```
(define (n2t n)
  (define 1to19     '(one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve
                          thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen))
  (define multof10  '(twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety))
  (define thousands '(thousand million billion trillion quadrillion quintillion sextillion septillion octillion nonillion decillion undecillion))
  (cond
    ((= n 0) '(zero))  ; zero is a special case since from now on all 0 will be suppressed
    ((< n 0) (cons 'minus (n2t (- n))))
    (else
     (let loop ((n n) (units thousands) (res '()))
       (cond
         ; --- below 1000
         ((= n 0)    res)
         ((< 0 n 20) (cons (list-ref 1to19    (- n 1)) res))
         ((< n 100)  (cons (list-ref multof10 (- (quotient n 10) 2))
                           (loop (remainder n 10) '() res)))
         ((< n 1000) (loop (quotient n 100)
                           '()
                           (cons 'hundred (loop (remainder n 100) '() res))))
         (else
          ; --- 1000 and above
          (let ((q   (quotient n 1000))
                (res (loop (remainder n 1000) thousands res)))
            (if (zero? q)
                res
                (loop q (cdr units) (cons (car units) res))))))))))
```

Testing:

```
> (n2t 0)
'(zero)
> (n2t 1001)
'(one thousand one)
> (n2t 132219)
'(one hundred thirty two thousand two hundred nineteen)
> (n2t -132219)
'(minus one hundred thirty two thousand two hundred nineteen)
> (n2t 2345678213)
'(two billion three hundred forty five million six hundred seventy eight thousand two hundred thirteen)
> (n2t 2432902008176640000)
'(two quintillion four hundred thirty two quadrillion nine hundred two trillion eight billion one hundred seventy six million six hundred forty thousand)
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm unable to get this to work. 

define: not allowed in an expression context for the first 'define' functions.

Comment: Oh I see, I lost R5RS compatibility with my last edit... it's fixed now.

Comment: Awesome this helps a lot. @uselpa
 
I'm trying to figure out how to put in a factorial function. So I defined a function in the first part. To the extent of my knowledge itll compute it, but won't turn it into the list.  

So say i have (n2t (factorial 3)) -> (six).  

How do I go about adding this factorial function into the main code and return the list? It just needs to compute the value first then continue into that loop?

Comment: Why would you try to merge these 2 procedures? Each one does a different thing. What's wrong with `(n2t (factorial 3)) `?

Comment: Ahhh maybe not merge... but I am trying to see how to add factorial capability as well!

Comment: Not sure I understand you here... maybe you should ask a new question.

Comment: Got it. Thank you anyway for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know you should be able to do something like:

```
(number->english 2345678213) 
; ==> "two billion three hundred and fourtyfive million six \
;      hundred and seventyeight tousand two hundred and thirteen"
```

At first glimse you can see that there is a pattern:

```
...
<english number text below 1000> million
<english number text below 1000> thousand
<english number text below 1000>
```

Thus.. the procedure would perhaps look something like:

```
(define (number->english x)
  (if (zero? x)
      "zero"
      (iterate-thousands x thousands '()))
```

with `thousands` being defined as: `'("" "thousand" "million" "billion" "trillion" ...)` and `iterate-tousands` perhaps look something like this:

```
(define (iterate-thousands thousands x acc)
  (if (zero? x)
      (join acc " ")
      (iterate-thousands (cdr thousands)
                         (quotient x 1000)
                         (list* (below-1000 (remainder x 1000))
                                (car thousands) 
                                acc))))
```

Where `below-1000` returns a correct string for every number below 1000. It would typically divide the work according to the naming convention. That is something special for below 13, the teens until 19, compound the ty + ones until 99 and perhaps a recursion on the above that takes ones + " hundred " + recursion on the remainder so that `234` becomes `(string-append "two hundred and " (below-1000 34))`. `join` just use `string-append` with separator and handles empty strings correctly.

Comment: So would I be having to iterate through every number? Like if I want millions I have to iterate through million, hundred thousand,  thousand, ten, one. What if the number is larger than 1000?

Comment: Sorry, kind of a bad question. Do you have an example of how that'd look? I'm having a hard time visualising

Comment: @anitun the whole code for that iteration is there. It does it in reverse starting with 1000^0. Only thing I left out was `below-1000` which is fun to make.

Comment: Oh okay. I will try and work with this for now then!