# Scheme integer to string

Tags: scheme, racket

Write a procedure, NumtToStr that takes a positive integer argument and returns a sentence containing that number spelled out in words:

(NumToStr 82)
(EIGHTY TWO)

I don't understand how to take apart the list in scheme if the two arguements coming into the method are integers and not lists? And also once I do get one of the items how do i keep track of how long the number is to know if it is in the teens, hundreds, thousands, millions,etc?

UPDATE:
So i looked at the resources given in the comments but code like this with multiple definitions do not work in drRacket and give an error define: expected only one expression for the function body, but found 5 extra parts :

```
 (define (num->lst num)
  (define bases '(one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve
                  thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen))
  (define multiples '(twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety))
  (define units '(empty thousand million billion trillion quadrillion quintillion
                        sextillion septillion octillion nonillion decillion))
  (define (below-1000 num bases mults)
    (cond [(zero? num) empty]
          [(< num 20) (list (list-ref bases (sub1 num)))]
          [(< num 100) (list* (list-ref mults (- (quotient num 10) 2))
                              (below-1000 (remainder num 10) bases mults))]
          [else (list* (list-ref bases (sub1 (quotient num 100))) 'hundred
                       (below-1000 (remainder num 100) bases mults))]))
  (define (nsplit num lst units)
    (define q (quotient num 1000))
    (define r (remainder num 1000))
    (if (zero? num) lst
        (cond [(zero? r) (nsplit q lst (cdr units))]
              [else (nsplit q (append (below-1000 r bases multiples)
                                      (cons (car units) lst)) (cdr units))])))
  (if (zero? num) '(zero)
      (remove 'empty (nsplit num empty units))))
```

Comment: Perhaps you'll find [Converting numbers to english letter list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42660997/4739247), or, [(SCHEME) Number -> English List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35666978/4739247) helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting numbers to english letter list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660997/converting-numbers-to-english-letter-list)

Comment: Are you using one of the teaching languages in DrRacket? If so, you can move out all the `define`s on their own.

Comment: I am also trying to do this recursively instead of with the loops and car/cdrs.

Comment: From reading your update you are not using the correct language. In the dropdown below choose "Determine language from source" and have `#lang racket` as the first line. You have not written what language you use so I assume not using `#lang racket` is a user error.

Comment: I got this program to run I was just wondering if anyone had an idea of how to do this recursively